# Unit test assert with result after return;

Tags: java, android, junit

Let assume that:

```
void someMethod(Context context, int a){
if(context==null || a == 0){
return;
}
 //some code here
}
```

Is it possible to somehow test that it has stopped on this if statement if it is not returning anything?
I mean, I would like to put some kind of assert that checked "okey, context was null, so it stopped on this return".

Of course the problem is related that the class is void and it may be questionable why I'd like to test this kind of sort of methods, but I'd like to hear about some possibilities.

Comment: All you can test is whether there is an expected (or unexpected) state change of the instance on which you invoke `someMethod`, or `context`. And, ultimately, that's what you should be testing: test what the method does (state changes, or not), *not* how it does it (does it return on this line or that line).

Comment: @Andy Turner
Thanks for answer.
Yes, I am aware of that, but was wonder if there is some alternative solution for that kind of situation.

Comment: It's note related to your question, but I would reverse the conditional to avoid the `return`:  if(context!=null && a != 0){
 ....
}`

Comment: @Nimdokai well, no - what alternative would there be? JUnit is nothing more than Java code: if you can't do it in non-JUnit code, you can't do it in JUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a method has no return value, all you can test for is:

- State changes: whether there is an expected (or unexpected) state change of the instance on which you invoke `someMethod`, or `context`, or some other global state that might happen to be changed in the method.
- Exceptions: if `context` is `null`, and you don't return here, you may get a `NullPointerException` or some other type of exception subsequently. But you don't really need to check for this explicitly, since the JUnit test would fail if one occurs that you don't expect  (you just need to make sure that you're not accidentally swallowing that exception in your test).

And, ultimately, that's what you should be testing: test *what the method does* (state changes, exceptions thrown, return values (if you have one) etc), *not* how it does it (does it return on this line or that line).

Comment: Ok, thank you for answer I will keep that in mind :)